# XML related api in JDK

Tags: xml, java

I find there are a lot of packages in jdk 6 are xml related. such as:

- com.sun.org.apache.xerces.*
- com.sun.org.apache.xml.*
- com.sun.org.apache.xpath.*
- javax.xml.*
- org.w3c.dom.*
- org.w3c.xml.*

as a java newbie,  I want to know, how these xml related api orgnized? what can they do in xml related programing? please also mention the third part library those can do samilary job.

I used to use dom4j to do xml to object transform, and now I find we can using jaxb, which is built in jdk.

Comment: Read - [Java API for XML Processing (JAXP)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/index.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several APIs in the JDK

- **javax.xml.parers** - APIs for DOM/SAX parsing

  - **org.w3c.dom** - DOM related classes
  - **org.xml.sax** - SAX related classes
- **javax.xml.stream** - APIs for StAX (pull) parsing
- **java.xml.bind** - APIs for converting domain objects to/from XML.
- **javax.xml.transform** - Transforming one XML document to another using a XSLT stylesheet.
- **javax.xml.validation** - APIs for performing Schema validation
- **javax.xml.xpath** - APIs for querying an XML document.

**Using these APIs together**

These APIs can be used together in many different ways (below are examples from my blog):

- You could use the `javax.xml.validation` APIs to validate an object with JAXB annotations:

  - http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/validate-jaxb-object-model-with-xml.html
- You could use the `javax.xml.transform` APIs to transform an object with JAXB annotations:

  - http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/11/using-jaxb-with-xslt-to-produce-html.html
- You could apply a SAX `XMLFilter` to a SAX parser to affect how JAXB objects are unmarshalled:

  - http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/11/applying-namespace-during-jaxb-unmarshal.html
- You could unmarshal from a StAX `XMLStreamReader` to convert the middle of an XML document to objects.

  - http://blog.bdoughan.com/2012/08/handle-middle-of-xml-document-with-jaxb.html

**Note:**

The `com.sun.org.apache` APIs are from the implementations of the standard XML APIs included in the JDK, I would recommend not using them directly.  There are also alternate implementations of these standard APIs that can also be used that offer extensions beyond their corresponding specifications.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need JAXB: [JAXB example](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/). For me, Jaxb covers all needs in java.